# Updating breadcrumb component when sidebar component NavLinks are clicked

Tags: reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I'm trying to follow my program principles of good design and encapsulate different components of my app but I've run into a problem that I guess can be summarized as, I don't know how to get different components to communicate.

I'm using react, react-router, and material-ui.

I have a Sidebar Navigation Menu (SidebarMenu.js). This is literally the code from the material-ui dashboard example. This SidebarMenu component just returns a component that is a List of ListItems. Each with NavLinks inside for proper react-routing.

```
export default function SideBarMenu() {
const classes = useStyles();


return (
<>
<List>
      <ListItem button component={NavLink} to="/" exact activeClassName={classes.navLinkSelectedItem} >
        <ListItemIcon>
          <DashboardIcon />
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary="Home" />
      </ListItem>
      ...
```

Then I have a BreadCrumbs component. This is also basically a copy of the Breadcrumbs integrated with React Router seen on the material-ui example page under breadcrumbs.

```
    import { BrowserRouter, Link as RouterLink } from "react-router-dom";

    const breadcrumbNameMap = {
    '/main': 'Main',
    '/main/important': 'Important',
    '/trash': 'Trash',
    '/spam': 'Spam',
    '/drafts': 'Drafts',
    };

    function ListItemLink(props) {
    const { to, open, ...other } = props;
    const primary = breadcrumbNameMap[to];

    return (
      <li>
        <ListItem button component={RouterLink} to={to} {...other}>
          <ListItemText primary={primary} />
          {open != null ? open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore /> : null}
        </ListItem>
      </li>
    );
  }

  ListItemLink.propTypes = {
    open: PropTypes.bool,
    to: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
  };

  const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
      display: 'flex',
      flexDirection: 'column',
      width: 360,
    },
    lists: {
      backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.paper,
      marginTop: theme.spacing(1),
    },
    nested: {
      paddingLeft: theme.spacing(4),
    },
  }));

  const LinkRouter = (props) => <Link {...props} component={RouterLink} />;

  export default function MainBreadCrumbs() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
      <BrowserRouter initialEntries={['/main']} initialIndex={0}>
        <div className={classes.root}>
          <Route>
            {({ location }) => {
              const pathnames = location.pathname.split('/').filter((x) => x);

              return (
                <Breadcrumbs aria-label="breadcrumb">
                  <LinkRouter color="inherit" to="/">
                    Home
                  </LinkRouter>
                  {pathnames.map((value, index) => {
                    const last = index === pathnames.length - 1;
                    const to = `/${pathnames.slice(0, index + 1).join('/')}`;

                    return last ? (
                      <Typography color="textPrimary" key={to}>
                        {breadcrumbNameMap[to]}
                      </Typography>
                    ) : (
                      <LinkRouter color="inherit" to={to} key={to}>
                        {breadcrumbNameMap[to]}
                      </LinkRouter>
                    );
                  })}
                </Breadcrumbs>
              );
            }}
          </Route>
```

In my main Dashboard / App.js, I then use React Router to change which components are rendered based on the link, easy peasy (I thought)...

```
    return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Router>

      <AppBar position="absolute" className={ clsx(classes.appBar, open && classes.appBarShift) }>
        <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
         ... toolbar / menu junk ...
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>

      <Drawer
        variant="permanent"
        classes={{
          paper: clsx(classes.drawerPaper, !open && classes.drawerPaperClose),
        }}
        open={open}
      >
        <div className={classes.toolbarIcon}>
          <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
            <ChevronLeftIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </div>
        <Divider />
        <SideBarMenu/>
      </Drawer>
      <main className={classes.content}>
        <div className={classes.appBarSpacer} />
        <Container maxWidth="lg" className={classes.container}>
          <Switch>
          <MainBreadCrumbs/>
            <Route exact path="/">
              <Home/>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/schedule">
            <div>Scheduling Page</div>
            </Route>
            <Route path="/patient">
              <Dashboard />
            </Route>
            <Route path="/tasks">
            <div>Tasking Page</div>
            </Route>   
          </Switch>
        </Container>
      </main>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And here is where I go crazy.
The Sidebar navigation works perfectly. clicking the links renders the appropriate Dashboard components just as React Router should work. The issue is that there is clearly NO communication between clicking those NavLink links in the sidebar and telling the BreadCrumbs component to update itself with a new URL/link to parse.

Similarly if I artificially put few Links inside the BreadCrumbs component, I can click them, the URL changes, and the breadcrumbs is re-parsed and updated BUT it does not want to update the main dashboard or sidebar NavLinks to reflect the change.

Buttom line, I'm not sure if I've messed up my code or if I am lacking some necessity to allow for communication between components, but ifs the later, but I am at a loss as to what the "best" practices are for allowing cross-talk about router state between components. Does anyone have any examples out there to point me in the right direction or simple ways to fix the above examples to allow for this? Much appreciated in advance. I would very much like to keep my components separate for the sake of organization and simplicity in reading but the only fix I can think of would be to lump ALL of the above code into one ridiculously large Main App.

Cheers

Comment: Ah I'm an idiot. Solved my issue but I'll keep it here for other's to learn from my mistake. Specifically, inside my BreadCrumbs component, I wrapped the entire thing inside a BrowserRouter. But my main DashBoard app which includes the sidebar, navbar, and react-router switch/route logic was ALSO wrapped by a BrowserRouter. So I guess I effectively had a BrowserRouter controlling almost everything, but then a second nested one just for the BreadCrumbs which makes no sense. Removing that literally fixed the entire problem and now the two seem to behave nicely together...

Comment: Good to hear that you solved your problem:) You can post your comment as an answer and after 48 hours you can accept it, so people who wants to help can just see the answered icon and don't spend time on reading the question.